# Location for Network Location Server

Tags: direct-access

I am working on setting up Direct Access, and a network location server is required. Is there a best practice on where to install it?

The requirement are that it only be accessible from the intranet. So I'm thinking on the ADFS server since it has IIS, another option is the AD controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put it on your ADFS box.  Typically you don't want anything running on your DCs other than the AD DS stuff.  Whenever you can separate roles however that is a good practice, just not always realistic.

Comment: thats was I was thinking, just wanted to double check.